# String.replaceAll for multiple characters

Tags: java

I have a line with `^||^` as my delimiter, I am using

```
int charCount = line.replaceAll("[^" + fileSeperator + "]", "").length();  
if(fileSeperator.length()>1)
{  
    charCount=charCount/fileSeperator.length();
    System.out.println(charCount+"char count between");  
}
```

This does not work if i have a line that has stray `|` or `^` as it counts these as well. How can i modify the regex or any other suggestions?

Comment: Can you show examples of your line here?

Comment: ^||^0^||^27111500^||^GS-21F-0196X^||^7^||^0^||^F^||^ Item: Ice Hard|Soft|temp|3^4|under|hello^||^

Comment: Could you explain what you want your code to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, what you're really trying to do is count the number of times that `^||^` appears in your String.

If that's the case, you can use:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote("^||^")).matcher(line);
int count = 0;
while ( m.find() ) 
    count++;

System.out.println(count + "char count between");
```

But you really don't need the regex engine for this.

```
int startIndex = 0;
int count = 0;
while ( true ) {
    int newIndex = line.indexOf(fileDelimiter, startIndex);
    if ( newIndex == -1 ) {
        break;
    } else {
        startIndex = newIndex + 1;
        count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: just one doubt . This ignore every occurrence of a single | or a single ^ character right

Comment: hi mark the second part of your answer matches the output i require but the 1st answer does not . It gives me a count of 0 while escaping the | with \\

Comment: and i also want the 1st part of the answer to work for me for a certain situation where i want the record of a particular column no

Comment: @justin3250: I think I fixed it (though admittedly I haven't tested it).  The `^` needs to be escaped too as it's a special regex character.  But if you want to treat it as a literal it's easiest to use `Pattern.quote()`.

Answer (score 2):

Certain characters have special meanings in a regular expression, such as `^` and `|`.  These must be escaped with a backslash in order for them to be treated as normal characters and not as special characters.  For example, the following regular expression matches all caret (`^`) and pipe (`|`) characters (note the backslashes): `[\^\|]`

The `Pattern.quote()` method can be used to escape all of the special characters in a given String.

```
String quoted = Pattern.quote("^||^"); //returns "\^\|\|\^";
```

Also note that a **character class only matches one character**.  Thus, the regex `[^\^\|\|\^]` will match all characters except `^` and `|`, **not** all characters except the sequence `^||^`.  If your intention is to count the number of delimiters (`^||^`) in a String, then a better approach might be to use the `String.indexOf(String, int)` method.

Answer (score 1):

Mark Peters's answer seems better. I edited so my answer won't cause any confusion.

Comment: This will replace ^ and | separately, not locate the full separator string.

Comment: Yes it was just a sample .. he can replace with his separator.

Comment: In which case, why would multiple replaces be needed?

Comment: Well I posted before he specified his line so I understood that the separator can show up together or one at a time .. in which case he would need to replace them TOGETHER and after, one at a time :) (not necessary in that order)

Comment: With you. Might want to change your answer in line with the update ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should replace it like this with proper escaping since your delimiter has all special character of regex:

```
line.replaceAll("\\^\\|\\|\\^", "");
```

OR else **don't use regex at all** and call replace method like this:

```
line.replace("^||^", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Lazy solutions.

Depending on the end goal (the println statement is a little confusing):

```
int numberOfDelimiters = (line.length() - line.replace(fileSeparator,"").length()) 
                         / fileSeparator.length();

int numberOfNonDelimiterChars = line.replace(fileSeparator,"").length();
```